# Redirect folder link to xml file

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, redirect

So I recently switched away from wordpress. Wordpress keeps all of it's feed URLs at /feed/. This seems reasonable to me, so I never signed up for a site like feedburner.

Now I'm using an entirely new blog software, and it puts the feed at /atom.xml.

How can I use the .htaccess file to redirect requests to /feed/ to /atom.xml? Or maybe redirect requests to both to a feedburner url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^feed/ /atom.xml [L,R=301]
```

You can replace ´/atom.xml` with any absolute URL or URL path you want.